# Input type range limit to grabbing handle only

Tags: html, range

Is there a way of limiting the changing of a range value to dragging the handle only?

I want to disable the handle jumping to wherever I click on the range.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="50">
```

Comment: put your code snippet for better clarity and help

Comment: I would imagine that to be a potential usability issue… People with limited motor/input skills may have problems with holding and dragging and depend on the click behaviour…?

Comment: @deceze That maybe true but I was just wondering if it can be turned off.

Comment: Different browsers may also present very different input methods; mobile browsers for instance may opt for something entirely different than a draggable bar. As such, what you're asking for may not even be applicable in certain situations, and you may find other things you'd want to modify in those situations. So… just leaving it as is is your best option here.

Answer (score 1):

CSS can be used for that. Apply `pointer-events: none` to the input and able them for the thumbs with `pointer-events: all`.

```css
input[type="range"] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
}
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
}
```